How are we covered in relation to using pictures from BrickSet and other sites?
In my recent answer to a question I've used rather a lot of images from BrickLink. Is there a need to get in touch with BrickLink and the other main LEGO sites for permission to use their images.
I know that submissions to this site is made under a Creative Commons license but I don't know how that affects stuff from other domains, and I expect the sites can take the bandwidth hit, but shoudln't we ask out of common courtesy? Also a lot of them get re-uploaded to imgur through the SE uploader.

Caveat: I am not a lawyer, everything here is my uneducated opinion.
It depends on the site in question really - for example LUGNet explicitly state that you can re-use their images, bit yes, you should really use the "link to image from web" in the image upload to move the images to imgur instead of pulling them directly from there.
Where I've pulled images from a forum post or similar, I've provided a link back to the original post and attribution.
For your answer I'd ensure that all the set numbers are linked, and then it's fairly obvious where the images came from.
